# How to remove an object from JSON response object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON response that appears as shown below. What I am trying to accomplish remove an object from the vaiable with a specifc key value pair using javascript

JSON Response.

```
console.log(userJSON); //response is below.

[Object {startDate="1403496000", name="user10"}, 
Object {startDate="1401681600", name="user11"}, 
Object {startDate="1423544400", name="user12"}, 
Object {startDate="1370836800", name="user13"}, 
Object {startDate="1370836800", name="user14"}, 
Object {startDate="1370750400", name="user15"}, 
Object {startDate="1402286400", name="user16"}, 
Object {startDate="1404273600", name="user17"}]
```

I want to be able to remove user10's object completly with the given variable name

Logic

```
var removeUser = user15;

//Do logic.

updatedUserJSON = 
    [Object {startDate="1403496000", name="user10"}, 
    Object {startDate="1401681600", name="user11"}, 
    Object {startDate="1423544400", name="user12"}, 
    Object {startDate="1370836800", name="user13"}, 
    Object {startDate="1370836800", name="user14"}, 
    Object {startDate="1402286400", name="user16"}, 
    Object {startDate="1404273600", name="user17"}]
```

Can someone help me get started on how to accomplish this using javascript? Would very much appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Note: JSON is just a data format. Once parsed and interactive, the values are JavaScript Objects, Arrays, etc.

Comment: ^ Meaning your problem has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski Thank you for letting me know that! TIL appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var nameToDelete = 'user15';

for(var index=0; index < userJSON.length; index++)
{
    if (userJSON[index].name == nameToDelete)
    {
        userJSON.splice(index,1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey @paul, if I wanted to remove all "user15" occurrences how would I go about doing this?

Comment: just remove the `break;`